# Access CouchDB with XHR using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, couchdb, jsonp

I've been looking into CouchDB recently and I'm currently having the problem that I don't know how I would access it using Javascript.

As far as I know at the moment my options are:

- XHR: Doesn't work. Same-Origin-Policy is in the way. I also don't seem to be able to make CouchDB send the additional `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.
- JSONP: Limits the request to the `GET` method.

So how do I access the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CouchDB does not support cross-origin queries at this time. (I have a patch submitted that I expect to be in the next release.)

The vast majority of CouchDB users are doing one of two things:

1. Serving the web page directly from CouchDB (no cross-origin problems)
2. Serving web page normally, and the server queries CouchDB, possibly proxying the XHR

Comment: I went for the second approach. Looking forward to cross-origin support though ;)